# Interact with Interface<T> method on a list of varying implementations

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface `IGenerator`. This interface mandates a method `Generate` that returns a generic type.
This interface is implemented by a variety of classes `NameGenerator`, `PostcodeGenerator`, `NHSNumberGenerator`.

```
public interface IGenerator
{
}
public interface IGenerator<T> : IGenerator
{
    T Generate();
}
```

Now I'm looking to export a populated 2D List of `IGenerator` implementations to csv.

```
public class ExportRow : List<IGenerator>
{
}
public class ExportFile : List<ExportRow>
{
    public string Name;
}
```

I iterate through each element in each row calling Generate().ToString(), all of the custom types like `Name` have ToString() implementations and it's all coming out to strings in the end as it's a csv.
The problem is I can't do `foreach` iteration with `element` as `IGenerator` as `IGenerator` doesn't have the `Generate()` method, only `IGenerator<T>` does and when I iterate with `element` as `IGenerator<object>` I get the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'RegistryFaker.Generator.NHSNumberGenerator' to type 'RegistryFaker.Generator.IGenerator1[System.Object]'.'`

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ExportPath);

string line;
foreach (ExportRow row in File)
{
    line = "";
    foreach (IGenerator<object> element in row)
    {
        line = line + element.Generate().ToString();
        if (!(element == row[row.Count - 1])) //is element (not) last in the row
        {
            line = line + ",";
        }
    }
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
writer.Close();
```

I considered replacing `T Generate()` with `string Generate()` but I want to use these generators for purposes other than csv so preserving types is important.

How can I interact with the `IGenerator<T>` objects in the 2D array so that I can call `Generate()` on them?

Comment: You just expect that ToString() delivers a line valid for csv from any T. That sounds wrong. Let T implement an interface that delivers what you want as csv representation for example. Having a non-generic overload of a factory method sounds pretty normal also. The returned object from that method can then be casted into the interface that knows the csv line creation method.

Comment: ToString() delivers a column in a line not the whole line. You are right though that I don't mandate that a custom ToString() implementation has been created which could end up falling back the the default object.ToString() which would be bad. How could I mandate that the IGenerator<object> elements in the loop have implemented this IToString intrerface?

Comment: Put a constraint on the interface definition `public interface IGenerator<T> : IGenerator where T : IMyLovelyCSVToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your generic interface to be covariant (like `IEnumerable<T>`) to be able to cast `IGenerator<DerivedType>` to `IGenerator<BaseType>`

```
public interface IGenerator<out T> : IGenerator // 'out'
{
    T Generate();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the type of `element` is `IGenerator` (non-generic).

Comment: I hadn't heard of covariance but this solved the problem! Thankyou!